# How to Clear Every Third Box in a Row?

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to create an efficient, clean layout for an e-commerce site. This site is being built in-house for my client, I am in charge only of the CSS and basic structure.

I would like to figure out the best STRUCTURAL way to clear every third box in a row. When the boxes are all the same size they float naturally in a grid, but when one of them changes size based on content (this will be common on the site) the boxes shift improperly and break the layout.

I considered/tried two options:

1. I can manually place a div container, with "clear" styles after every third box.
2. I can wrap the boxes in groups of 3, and use element:after to place a clear in this container, which would effectively clear the 3 boxes in the row.

Is one of these options better than the other? I know that the "clear" div is not preferable, but is creating a new container to wrap around the 3 boxes that much better? Either way I am still adding a new HTML element to the page.

Is there another option that I am missing? I know it's possible to do either of these options dynamically, but I want to make sure that I choose the more efficient option for this project. That is, I don't have to worry about how the code will be functionally written, I just need to figure out how the final structure will look.

I'm not experienced with this kind of layout and I don't know if there might be things that I haven't discovered yet, as for how to do this.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code, or provide a http://jsfiddle.net explaining what you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your top level wrapper has a fixed width in which you would like to fit the rows of 3 boxes each,  the best solution is to put a row-container div with clear:both css styling as in the code below

```
    <html>
<body>
<style>
   #box_wrapper{
      max-width:200px;
      border: 2px blue  solid;
   }
   .row_container{
      clear:both;
      border: 1px yellow solid;
   }   
   .box{
       width:50px;
       height:50px;
       float:left;
       border: 1px red dotted;
   }
</style>
<div id="box_wrapper" width="200" height="200">
  <div class="row_container">
          <div class="box" id="box_1"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_2"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_3"></div>          
  </div>
  <div class="row_container">
          <div class="box" id="box_4"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_5"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_6"></div>          
  </div>
  <div class="row_container">
          <div class="box" id="box_7"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_8"></div>
          <div class="box" id="box_9"></div>          
  </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the top level wrapper is a fixed width. They all flow correctly but only as long as they are all the same height, when the height changes the columns shift to make space for the new heights... This pretty much answers my question though, thank you very much!

Comment: Whats with the down-vote,  the answer was picked as correct by the owner, there is enough information to solve the issue .  Could someone enlighten me ?

Comment: if the question is a duplicate , then the question should be down-voted not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want every third item to have `clear: both;`

Lets assume these items are div's.  All of which are inside `<div id="container"></div>`.

Now, I would do the following:

```
#container div:nth-child(3n+1) {
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: When people answer the same after the correct one is given, it dissapoints me.  This one was first.

Comment: Actually it should be `:nth-child(3n+1)` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/uer0yL5m/

Comment: You're correct, I forgot it worked that way.

Comment: Clear:both would push the third element onto its own line, wouldn't it? The problem is that I need three containers in a row, then some sort of clear, then another three containers, etc. The clear is to make sure that the three elements in a row do not shift the layout if one of the elements is taller than the other (where the elements will push to the right because their space is being taken up). I'm sorry if my original message was confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :nth-child() CSS pseudo class to achieve this.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Example:

```
div:nth-child(3n) {
  clear:right;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was correct, but you changed it to `3n`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the support that you need to provide, you could use the CSS3 nth-child selector.

```
div:nth-child(3n) {
clear: right;
}
```

Or something similar depending on how everything else is setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the pseudo element `:nth-child()`

```
#element:nth-child(3n) {  
    clear:both;
}
```

Where `n` starts at 0 and goes up by one for each of that element type

Here's an overall look at `:nth-child()`
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp